# How to use C++ so library functions in C# in Ubuntu

Tags: c#, c++, import, cmake

There was an existing C++ library that achieves few operations. I want to perform these operations from a new cs application. On invoking calling from CS, I'm getting EntryPointNotFoundException.

I can modify the C++ library as well. So, I have placed three global functions in C++ library and made them exportable( visibility("Default") ).

```
// test.h
//     CPP functions to be re-used
#define LIB_VISIBLE __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#define LIB_EXTERN extern

class LIB_VISIBLE Info
{
    public:
    LIB_VISIBLE static int fun(){}  // Being called by funct
};
extern "C"
{
    typedef int32_t          pi_int;
    typedef int8_t           pi_bool;
    typedef int8_t *         pi_bool_ref;
    typedef double           pi_double;
    typedef void *           pi_IntPtr;
    typedef const char *     pi_string;
    typedef char *           pi_string_ref;

    LIB_VISIBLE LIB_EXTERN pi_bool funct(pi_string inPar, pi_string_ref outPar);  // <===== function to be reused
};

test.cpp
bool funct(char * inPar, char* outPar)
{
  // perform operations and return bool
}
```

Do I need to mention something in CMakeFileList.txt while creating the so file?

Any kind of input is appreciated.

Exception:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.EntryPointNotFoundException: funct
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Test.LibraryC.NativeMethods:funct ()
  at Test.TestI.Verify () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Try to make an exe of your C++ application then give the parameters to your C++ functions using `argv[]` array. After creating the exe using cmake, make a method in C# which executes this exe using `Process` class in the `System.Diagonostic` namespace.

Comment: Can you post more code samples as to what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Cannot create another process for the trivial operation and sorry Kunal, I can't post the actual code here. I'm just trying to establish the connection.